# How to build a grammar LL(1) for pseudocode

Tags: c, compiler-construction, grammar

I'm currenlty trying to build a grammar LL(1) for "pseudocode" but my main issue is about "design" I know I have to put operators, functions, sentnces, etc..

Here is part of my grammar, where I have a lot of troubles with recursive and it is ambiguous

```
condition -> logic | con_and | con_or
cond_or -> logic || logic
cond_and -> logic && logic
logic -> exp > exp | exp < exp | exp >= exp | exp <= exp | exp == exp | exp != exp
```

So as you can see, I have some troubles, it is ambiguous but I dont know how to design a good grammar so it can be LL(1)

Any advises please?

Comment: Have a look at the grammar of almost any programming language to see how this is done. Pascal is a good exampl.

Comment: Great idea , Im gonna look for it. Do You have a link ?